Maven install resulted in spring-utils 0.0.7-LOCAL failure
System: macOS Catalina (10.15.7)
Context: Novice command line user installing siSPOTR in conda environment using python 2.7. Unsure how to resolve the build failure. Ran the command "mvn install" but resulted in build failure.
Maven version: Apache Maven 3.9.8 (NON_CANONICAL)
(py27) toph@Christophers-MacBook-Pro sispotr-project % mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for edu.uiowa.icts.research:SafeSeed-base:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 228, column 27
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] spring-utils                                                       [jar]
[INFO] SafeSeed-base                                                      [jar]
[INFO] SafeSeed                                                           [war]
[INFO] sispotr-parent                                                     [pom]
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< edu.uiowa.icts.spring:spring-utils >-----------------
[INFO] Building spring-utils 0.0.7-LOCAL                                  [1/4]
[INFO]   from spring-utils/pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-244
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ spring-utils ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources from src/main/resources to target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ spring-utils ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 28 source files to /Users/toph/sispotr-project/spring-utils/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: Source option 7 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later.
[ERROR] error: Target option 7 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later.
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] spring-utils 0.0.7-LOCAL ........................... FAILURE [  1.258 s]
[INFO] SafeSeed-base 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] SafeSeed 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] sispotr-parent 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.433 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-07-24T15:51:16+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project spring-utils: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] error: Source option 7 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later.
[ERROR] error: Target option 7 is no longer supported. Use 8 or later.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException


This question is similar to: Error "Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later" on Maven compile. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
